# how to import my own package from ipython

Tags: python, module, package, ipython

I have my own repository created in BitBucket.
In that repository, I have a file named `core.py` and an `__init__.py` file

I tried to import the core module, and I fixed all the requirements that were needed.
Now when I am finally able to import the module using ipython, 
which is only one big class, with the call:

```
obj = MyClass()
```

I get an error:

```
name 'MyClass()' is not defined
```

even though it seems the module was imported.
Let me know if more information is Needed.

Comment: Can you add your import statement? I.E. How did you import "MyClass"?

Comment: sure, let's be more specific and less generic:
    from mintigocloudstorage import core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in your comment, you are importing core.py:

```
from mintigocloudstorage import core
```

That means, you also have to tell your script where to find your class:

```
obj = core.MyClass()
```

If the import was sucessfull as you say, Python should now be able to locate your classes definition.

Alternatively you can also import your class:

```
from mintigocloudstorage.core import MyClass
obj = MyClass()
```

Comment: i did as you say.  from mintigocloudstorage.core import My class. now i try 
obj = MyClass() and i get a new error:  __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: That would mean your script can now find your custom class but you defined it with a signature that expects arguments when being created. (Your __init__ function expects you to pass 2 additional arguments). If that doesnt do it, please post your classes definition /edit your post :)